# How to get _fbp and _fbc while Installing Meta Pixel on my NodeJS site?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, facebook-pixel

**How to get _fbp and _fbc while Installing Meta Pixel?**

I am trying to install Meta Pixel on my website.

According to facebook, the _fbp and _fbc are stored under browser cookies.

My approach is this:

```
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const fbp = req.cookies['_fbp'];
const fbc = req.cookies['_fbc'];
```

and pass these values to Facebook API?

Is this the correct approach?

Comment: Why it would not be? What could be the issue? Actually, your question is opinion based